# function pointers and enum in C

Tags: c, enums, function-pointers

I am looking for a fancy way to link function pointers and enums.

In my case I have a message queue that holds a event id and some data associated with the event.
some simple pseudo code:

```
event=(eid, data)
switch(eid) {
    case eid1:
        handler1(data);
        break;
    case edi2:
        handler2(data);
        break;

}
```

Now I like to do some optimization. If the event id has the value of the function called inside of the switch case statement I can save the switch case decode by preserving a nice readability of the code.

```
event=(eid, data)
eid(data)
```

Now if I am putting it into an example like:

```
static void abc(void * p) {

}

static void abc2(void * p) {

}

enum eventId {
    eid1 = abc,
    eid2 = abc2
} xyz;
```

My compiler tells:

```
error: enumerator value for 'eid1' is not an integer constant eid1 = abc
```

What is absolutely right.

Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: The address of `abc` and `abc2` is not known at compile time.

Comment: You should inspect the assembly generated from an optimized compilation. The computed goto that results from an optimized switch might be good enough leaving the source code easier to understand.

Comment: guess this is a typical compiler linker problem. after linking we know the address of 'abc' ans 'abc2' but not at compile time. Sounds like the problem of assigning a function pointer to an enum can't be solved. Maybe the compiler can be told that he enum value is getting later resolved (like a foreward declartion)

Comment: Enums are integers, not pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array of function pointers, and use the `enum` as the index.

```
typedef void (*handler_func)(void *);
handler_func event_handlers[] = { abc, abc2 };
enum eventId {
    eid1 = 0,
    eid2 = 1,
    eid_max
}

if (eid < eid_max) event_handlers[eid](data);
```

Answer (score 2):

`enums` cannot be linked with other data in `C`, but the preprocessor can generate code for you in the form of [X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*handler_func)(void *);

static void handler1(void *const param) {
    printf("Event 1: %p.\n", param);
}

static void handler2(void *const param) {
    printf("Event 2: %p.\n", param);
}

#define EVENT(X) \
    X(EID1, &handler1), \
    X(EID2, &handler2)

#define PARAMA(A, B) A
#define PARAMB(A, B) B
#define STRINGISEA(A, B) #A

enum Event { EVENT(PARAMA) };
static const handler_func event_handlers[] = { EVENT(PARAMB) };
static const char *const event_strings[] = { EVENT(STRINGISEA) };
/* Everything will be the same size, pick one. */
static const size_t event_size = sizeof event_strings / sizeof *event_strings;

int main(void) {
    size_t i;
    void *const param = (void *)0x100;
    for(i = 0; i < event_size; i++) {
        printf("Calling %s.\n", event_strings[i]);
        event_handlers[i](param);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Gives,

```
Calling EID1.
Event 1: 0x100.
Calling EID2.
Event 2: 0x100.
```

The advantage of this implementation is it's a [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself); if one decided to add more `events`, they will only need to be added in one spot. The disadvantage is it's hard to read.

Comment: You're missing `#define X`?

Comment: `X` is the parameter of the macro `EVENT(X)`. (See the other answer for a different way.)

Comment: I think whatever syntax is the most understandable and maintainable you should use; this one offers ease with multiple X-Macros. If one's data is unchanging, constant across multiple versions of one's programme, there's not much reason to use x-macros in the first place unless one has a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to the answer of @Barmar, you can use a technique called **X macro**, to keep corresponding (eid, handler) pairs in order. Note that you need only to change the definition of `LIST_OF_EVENTS` macro, adding or deleting pairs as needed.

```
void handler1(void*);
void handler2(void*);
void handler3(void*);

#define LIST_OF_EVENTS X(eid1, handler1), X(eid2, handler2), X(eid3, handler3)

#define X(id, x) id
enum evID { LIST_OF_EVENTS };
#undef X

#define X(x, handler) handler
void (*handlers[])(void*) = { LIST_OF_EVENTS };
#undef X

int get_event(void**);

void event_loop(void)
{
    for (;;) {
        void *data;
        int eid = get_event(&data);
        handlers[eid](data);
    }
}
```

Macro defitions expand to

```
enum evID { eid1, eid2, eid3 };
void (*handlers[])(void*) = { handler1, handler2, handler3 };
```