# Is there a way to "synchronize" the identifiers in an enum and function names called by a function pointer array?

Tags: c, enums, stm32, function-pointers

I am writing C code on STM32 (specifically the STM32756-EVAL) and I have created an enum which reads an incoming char array and assigns an enum to it. The value of this enum is then placed as the index for a function pointer array.

The reason why I have this code is to be able to decide on what function to call based on the receiving char array, without relying on a giant if-else stack reading through the char arrays one by one.

The relevant code:

```
enum cmd cmd_Converter(unsigned char* inputCmd){//Converts the input cmd from uint8_t to an enum.
    switch (inputCmd[0]){   //Currently we are using a switch-case. I expect this list to expand to something like 50.
    case 'F':
        if (memcmp(inputCmd, "FIRMV", COMMAND_LENGTH) == 0) return FIRMV;
        else return INVAL;
        break;
    case 'V':
        if (memcmp(inputCmd, "VALCN", COMMAND_LENGTH) == 0) return VALCN;
        else return INVAL;
        break;
    default:
        return INVAL;
    }
}

void process_Message(uint8_t* message, uint16_t Len){
    unsigned char inputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    unsigned char inputData[DATA_LENGTH];   
    unsigned char outputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    unsigned char outputData[DATA_LENGTH];

    //Function that separates message, inputCmd, and inputMessage.
    memcpy((char*) inputCmd, (const char*)message + COMMAND_CHAR, COMMAND_LENGTH);
    memcpy((char*) inputData, (const char*)message + DATA_CHAR, DATA_LENGTH);
    enum cmd enumCmd = cmd_Converter(inputCmd);
    void (*cmd_Function_Pointer[])(unsigned char* inputData) = {FIRMV_F, VALCN_F, INVAL_F}; //Is this even needed?
    (*cmd_Function_Pointer[enumCmd])(inputData);

//  message_Received(message, Len);
//  send_Message(outputCmd, outputData);
}

void FIRMV_F(unsigned char *inputData){
    //Do thing
}

void VALCN_F(unsigned char *inputData){
    //Do thing
}

void INVAL_F(unsigned char *inputData){
    //Do thing
}
```

The enum is there to improve code readability, so that anyone reading the code can see the enum and the function pointer and go "enum FIRMV will call FIRMV_F from (*cmd_Function_Pointer[enumCmd])(inputData)". One of the weaknesses I've identified is that it relies on the sequence of enum cmd and cmd_Function_Pointer[] to be identical, and if the list of enums gets too long it will be hard to maintain this identical sequence.

I am wondering whether there are any methods within C that would allow for "synchronizing" the identifiers in an enum and function names called by a function pointer?

The full code:
usbd_cdc_if.c

```
/**
  * @brief  Data received over USB OUT endpoint are sent over CDC interface
  *         through this function.
  *
  *         @note
  *         This function will issue a NAK packet on any OUT packet received on
  *         USB endpoint until exiting this function. If you exit this function
  *         before transfer is complete on CDC interface (ie. using DMA controller)
  *         it will result in receiving more data while previous ones are still
  *         not sent.
  *
  * @param  Buf: Buffer of data to be received
  * @param  Len: Number of data received (in bytes)
  * @retval Result of the operation: USBD_OK if all operations are OK else USBD_FAIL
  */
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);

  memset (buffer, '\0', 64);  // clear the buffer
  uint8_t len = (uint8_t)*Len;  //Converts Len as uint32_t to len as uint8_t
  memcpy(buffer, Buf, len);  // copy the data to the buffer
  memset(Buf, '\0', len);   // clear the Buf also
  //Code used to send message back

  process_Message(buffer, len);
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}

/**
  * @brief  CDC_Transmit_FS
  *         Data to send over USB IN endpoint are sent over CDC interface
  *         through this function.
  *         @note
  *
  *
  * @param  Buf: Buffer of data to be sent
  * @param  Len: Number of data to be sent (in bytes)
  * @retval USBD_OK if all operations are OK else USBD_FAIL or USBD_BUSY
  */
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
{
  uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 7 */
  USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;
  if (hcdc->TxState != 0){  //If TxState in hcdc is not 0, return USBD_BUSY.
    return USBD_BUSY;
  }
  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, Buf, Len);    //SetTxBuffer sets the size of the buffer, as well as the buffer itself.
  result = USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);  //USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(&hUsbDeviceFS) transmits
  /* USER CODE END 7 */
  return result;
}
```

messageprocesser.c

```
#include "messageprocesser.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "string.h"

//Sample cmd: TOARM_FIRMV_00000000_4C\r\n
#define MESSAGE_LENGTH 25
#define COMMAND_CHAR 6  //See SW Protocol or sample cmd
#define COMMAND_LENGTH 5
#define DATA_CHAR 12
#define DATA_LENGTH 8
#define CHECKSUM_CHAR 21
#define CHECKSUM_LENGTH 2

enum cmd {FIRMV, VALCN, INVAL};

enum cmd cmd_Converter(unsigned char* inputCmd){//Converts the input cmd from uint8_t to an enum.
    switch (inputCmd[0]){
    case 'F':
        if (memcmp(inputCmd, "FIRMV", COMMAND_LENGTH) == 0) return FIRMV;
        else return INVAL;
        break;
    case 'V':
        if (memcmp(inputCmd, "VALCN", COMMAND_LENGTH) == 0) return VALCN;
        else return INVAL;
        break;
    default:
        return INVAL;
    }
}

void process_Message(uint8_t* message, uint16_t Len){
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_10);
    unsigned char inputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];     //These are not null-terminated strings.
    unsigned char inputData[DATA_LENGTH];           //These are just an array of chars.
    unsigned char outputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    unsigned char outputData[DATA_LENGTH];

    //Function that separates message, inputCmd, and inputMessage.
    memcpy((char*) inputCmd, (const char*)message + COMMAND_CHAR, COMMAND_LENGTH);
    memcpy((char*) inputData, (const char*)message + DATA_CHAR, DATA_LENGTH);
    enum cmd enumCmd = cmd_Converter(inputCmd);
    void (*cmd_Function_Pointer[])(unsigned char* inputData) = {FIRMV_F, VALCN_F, INVAL_F};
    (*cmd_Function_Pointer[enumCmd])(inputData);
}

void FIRMV_F(unsigned char *inputData){
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_10);
    unsigned char outputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    unsigned char outputData[DATA_LENGTH];
    memcpy(outputCmd, "FIRMV", COMMAND_LENGTH);
    memcpy(outputData, "01050A00", DATA_LENGTH);
    send_Message(outputCmd, outputData);
}

void VALCN_F(unsigned char *inputData){
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_10);
    unsigned char outputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    unsigned char outputData[DATA_LENGTH];
    memcpy(outputCmd, "VALCN", COMMAND_LENGTH);
    memcpy(outputData, "00000000", DATA_LENGTH);
    send_Message(outputCmd, outputData);
}

void INVAL_F(unsigned char *inputData){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_10);
    unsigned char outputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    unsigned char outputData[DATA_LENGTH];
    memcpy(outputCmd, "REEEE", COMMAND_LENGTH);
    memcpy(outputData, "99999999", DATA_LENGTH);
    send_Message(outputCmd, outputData);
}

void send_Message(uint8_t* cmd, uint8_t* data){
    uint8_t outputMessage[MESSAGE_LENGTH] = "TOWST_";
    memcpy((char*) outputMessage + COMMAND_CHAR, (const char*) cmd, COMMAND_LENGTH);
    outputMessage[COMMAND_CHAR + COMMAND_LENGTH] = '_';
    memcpy((char*) outputMessage + DATA_CHAR, (const char*) data, DATA_LENGTH);
    outputMessage[DATA_CHAR + DATA_LENGTH] = '_';

    //Deal with checksum
    int outputCheckSum = checkSum_Generator(outputMessage);
    char outputCheckSumHex[2] = {'0', '0'};
    itoa (outputCheckSum, outputCheckSumHex, 16);
    if (outputCheckSum < 16) { //Adds a 0 if CS has fewer than 2 numbers
        outputCheckSumHex[1] = outputCheckSumHex[0];
        outputCheckSumHex[0] = '0';
    }
    outputCheckSumHex[0] = toupper (outputCheckSumHex[0]);
    outputCheckSumHex[1] = toupper (outputCheckSumHex[1]);

    memcpy((char*) outputMessage + CHECKSUM_CHAR, (const char*) outputCheckSumHex, CHECKSUM_LENGTH);
    outputMessage[23] = '\r';
    outputMessage[24] = '\n';

    //return a processed message array

    CDC_Transmit_FS(outputMessage, sizeof(outputMessage));
}

int checkSum_Generator(uint8_t* message){
      int checkSum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < CHECKSUM_CHAR; i++){  //Gives the cs of TOARM_COMND_DATA0000_.
          checkSum ^= message[i];
      }
      return checkSum;
}
```

**The attempts at solving this issue**

[Another question that involved "linking function pointers and enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669810/function-pointers-and-enum-in-c) that I have looked into, but the solution offered doesn't seem to fix the issue I have mentioned, only circumventing by having smaller code.

So far I have tried changing the names of the functions to become identical to their enum counterparts, renaming FIRMV_F() to FIRMV(). Unsurprisingly, I got this:

```
../Core/Src/messageprocesser.c:59:6: error: 'FIRMV' redeclared as different kind of symbol
```

I have also tried assigning the function pointer array in a way similar to conventional arrays:

```
void process_Message(uint8_t* message, uint16_t Len){
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_10);
    unsigned char inputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];     //These are not null-terminated strings.
    unsigned char inputData[DATA_LENGTH];   //These are just an array of chars.
    unsigned char outputCmd[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    unsigned char outputData[DATA_LENGTH];

    //Function that separates message, inputCmd, and inputMessage.
    memcpy((char*) inputCmd, (const char*)message + COMMAND_CHAR, COMMAND_LENGTH);
    memcpy((char*) inputData, (const char*)message + DATA_CHAR, DATA_LENGTH);
    enum cmd enumCmd = cmd_Converter(inputCmd);
    void (*cmd_Function_Pointer[INVAL + 1])(unsigned char* inputData);
    (*cmd_Function_Pointer[FIRMV]) = FIRMV_F;
    (*cmd_Function_Pointer[VALCN]) = VALCN_F;
    (*cmd_Function_Pointer[INVAL]) = INVAL_F;
    (*cmd_Function_Pointer[enumCmd])(inputData);    //What is going on here?
}
```

I have gotten the following errors.

```
../Core/Src/messageprocesser.c:52:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   52 |  (*cmd_Function_Pointer[FIRMV]) = FIRMV_F;
      |                                 ^
../Core/Src/messageprocesser.c:53:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   53 |  (*cmd_Function_Pointer[VALCN]) = VALCN_F;
      |                                 ^
../Core/Src/messageprocesser.c:54:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   54 |  (*cmd_Function_Pointer[INVAL]) = INVAL_F;
```

This makes sense since my understanding is that the functions FIRMV_F do not have an lvalue, but I do not know how to fix it, assuming it is possible.

Please let me know if more detail or clarity is needed.

**To Less Determined Readers:** Using enum as index in function pointer array for readability. In current code enum sequencing needs to be identical to function pointer sequence. This seems vulnerable. Want method of making sure enum sequencing stays identical to function pointer sequence.

Comment: You have a two-stage process which converts a string to an enum, then an enum to a function pointer. It would be simpler to just convert the string to the function pointer (in `cmd_Converter()`). Just an idea.

Comment: My first attempt was to use a giant if-else stack converting 50 strings into functions. It looked quite ugly and Yandre-devy, so I spoke to the software engineering stackexchange who suggested switch-case. In order for s-c to work I needed them as enums. Of course, if there is a string to function pointer that isn't a giant if-else stack, I would love to hear it.

Comment: What about the X Macro approach in the last answers of the question you linked?

Comment: `(*cmd_Function_Pointer[FIRMV])` should be `cmd_Function_Pointer[FIRMV]`

Comment: @nielsen X macros should be the last resort. Very useful when maintaining old crap where you can't change much, but designing with them in new programs is not something I recommend. I did post an X macro version of my answer here though, for completeness.

Comment: You can also write `... = {[FIRMV] = FIRMV_F, [VALCN] = VALCN_F, ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a common recommended practice, assuming enum values are just sequential. Make an enum like this:

```
typedef enum
{
  INVAL,
  FIRMV,
  VALCN,
  CMD_N // number of items in the enum
} cmd_t;
```

And a function template like this:

```
typedef void cmd_func_t (unsigned char *inputData);
```

Then you can create an array of function pointers where each index corresponds to the relevant enum, by using designated initializers:

```
static cmd_func_t* const cmd_list[] =   // size not specified on purpose
{
  [INVAL] = INVAL_F,
  [FIRMV] = FIRMV_F,
  [VALCN] = VALCN_F,
};
```

Verify integrity with:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof cmd_list/sizeof cmd_list[0] == CMD_N,
               "cmd_list has wrong size compared to cmd_t");
```

Function call usage, for example:

```
cmd_list[FIRMV](param);
```

---

Also, just for completeness, we can go completely loco with "do not repeat yourself" and generate a lot of this through X-macros: https://godbolt.org/z/zY1nh5M5T. Not really recommended since it makes the code look obscure, but quite powerful. For example strings like `"FIRMV"` could be generated at compile-time, as shown in that example.

Comment: While X-macros is overkill in this case, there is a matter of scale. If we were talking 50+ items, I would consider the X-macro approach and write an explanation in the code. Btw., the `_Static_assert` should not be needed in the X-macro version.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your cmd_Converter() function just return the function pointer that is required. You can still use a switch statement to remove the need to have a long if...else if... chain. This way you don't need any enums, nor arrays of function pointers, and there is nothing to keep in sync.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COMMAND_LENGTH 8

typedef void (*handler_t)(const unsigned char *arg);

void FIRMV_F(const unsigned char *inputData);

handler_t cmd_Converter(const unsigned char *inputCmd)
{
    handler_t result = NULL;

    switch (inputCmd[0])
    {
        case 'F':
            if (memcmp(inputCmd, "FIRMV", COMMAND_LENGTH) == 0)
                result = FIRMV_F;
            break;

        // more cases here.

        default:
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Edit: If you want a purely data-driven approach that avoids the switch statement altogether, you can have an array of structures mapping command names to function pointers. This still removes the need for enums - the mapping is explicit:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COMMAND_LENGTH 8

typedef void (*handler_t)(const unsigned char *arg);

typedef struct
{
    const char *name;
    handler_t fn_p;
} cmd_t;

void FIRMV_F(const unsigned char *inputData);
void VALCN_F(const unsigned char *inputData);

static const cmd_t commands[] =
{
    {"FIRMV", FIRMV_F},
    {"VALCN", VALCN_F}
};

handler_t cmd_Converter(const unsigned char *inputCmd)
{
    handler_t result = NULL;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof commands / sizeof commands[0]; ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp((const char *)inputCmd, commands[i].name) == 0)
        {
            result = commands[0].fn_p;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is using a linear search. If you don't have many commands, this might be enough. If there are a lot, you could sort the array and do a binary search.

Comment: You'd still have a big old `switch` to maintain though, with all the branching it generates. Creating enum/function pairs is a pretty sound and useful design for many scenarios, such as when creating state machines.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed. If I was doing this, I'd have an array of structures containing the command name and function pointer, and search that. But I was answering the question that was asked.

Comment: @Lundin Updated to add a data-driven version with no switch.

Comment: Structs is an ok solution, it is readable and good design, but the advantage of having enum vs function pointer table is that you get direct access. No loops, no switches, no searching or strcmp, just a table look-up. As for your example here, it needs to be rewritten using `bsearch` when the total amount of items are some 50+.

Comment: @Lundin If they change their design to receive a number over USB then that would work. As it is, they are receiving a string over USB. There's going to have to be a `strcmp()` or similar somewhere.